# How do I remove quantcast from my sites?

Tags: plugin-jetpack, statistics

When I use ghostery on chrome, it finds Quantcast, wordpress stats and google analytics on my sites (nathanblack.com and knuckletattoos.com). I have jetpack and google analytics installed, but where is quantcast coming from and how do I remove it?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: I was looking at nathanblack.com and I did not find any quantcast code in your source (found wordpress stats and GA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantcast is coming from the Stats component of JetPack.

You can:

1. Disable Jetpack Stats
2. Directly block Quantcast, such as via the [DoNotTrack Plugin](http://blog.futtta.be/2011/02/17/why-your-wordpress-blog-needs-donottrack/)

Answer (score 0):

I found out Quant.js is also in Jetpack Comments because of the iFrame. What is your opinion about this blogpost of me and do you think I have to look out for other commenting system because I assume they are going to insert it back again (don't know for what purpose)....

So answer to question: also deactivate Jetpack Comments, check out  [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/quantjs-still-there-after-deactivating-stats?replies=4#post-3887210) .

Kind regards,

Comment: Hi, Willem, nice catch. Would be better if you included a summary of that forum thread. A Q&A site works differently from a forum, check the [about] page to get the general picture. Welcome to [wordpress.se]!